# Spring Configuration web-services: get XsdSchema from wsdl

Tags: java, spring, web-services, xsd, wsdl

I have Spring Web-Service Configuration.

```
public class WSConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
        public XsdSchema getSchema() {
            return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("wsdl/types/ewstypes.xsd"));
        }
...
```

How can I get xsd from wsdl?
Becouse I need elements from wsdl and I can't change this files(for example create new xsd from  and return it in @bean).

```
...
<wsdl:types>
            <xsd:schema xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jxb:version="2.0"
                        elementFormDefault="qualified"
                        targetNamespace="http://foo/equeue/ws/"
                    >

                <xsd:import namespace="http://foo/equeue/ws/types/" schemaLocation="../types/etypes.xsd"/>
                <xsd:import namespace="http://bar/123"  schemaLocation="../types/ewstypes.xsd" />

                <xsd:element name="getRequest" type="smev:GetRequestType"/>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple thing you can do is copying the tag

```
<xsd:schema>
```

from your WSDL with all its content to your file "ewstypes.xsd" and that results into a perfectly valid XSD schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" jxb:version="2.0"
                        elementFormDefault="qualified"
                        targetNamespace="http://foo/equeue/ws/"
                    >

                <xsd:import namespace="http://foo/equeue/ws/types/" schemaLocation="../types/etypes.xsd"/>
                <xsd:import namespace="http://bar/123"  schemaLocation="../types/ewstypes.xsd" />

                <xsd:element name="getRequest" type="smev:GetRequestType"/>
....
</xsd:schema>
```

Then expose it as a Bean as you're doing right now.
Hope this helps!